# ROS-I on melodic (ROS-Industrial)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
Does anyone have an idea of **when ROS-I will be officially released for Melodic**? I would really like to start migrating the support packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313335/ros-i-on-melodic-(ros-industrial)/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There currently isn't a planning/roadmap for this, but work has been started. See [ros-industrial/ros_industrial_issues#59](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_industrial_issues/issues/59).

> I would really like to start migrating the support packages.

Can you describe what it is that would need migration? The support pkgs typically only contain some meshes, a xacro and some launch files, which wouldn't seem to require migration at this point.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-23**:
Last time i tried to work with the support packages of staubli (early november 2018), they did not work with ROS Melodic.

It could have also been an error in the ROS-Industrial core package, which I built from source back then.

So are you saying all support packages should be compatible in the new

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-23**:\

> So are you saying all support packages should be compatible in the new

I can't say without knowing the error you mention.

[ros-industrial/industrial_core#204](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/pull/204) should allow building `industrial_core` on Melodic (Travis defaults to it).

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2019-01-23**:
Thank you. Will try that again.